# Eclipse restore point

Tags: java, eclipse

I have changed a lot of things in a java code but now I want to get my original code(the code before changing) back
For example it's for about 2 days ago
Is there any solution?

Comment: The "solution" was to use a source control system, of which Eclipse has support for many. Failing that, go back to your backups. Failing _that,_ consider this a valuable life lesson and be sure you change your ways :-)

Comment: I will consider this a valuable life lesson :D

Comment: It's cheating, but I'd also recommend working in a Dropbox folder, since that provides a history of your changes for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried restoring your code from Eclipse's local history? Right click on a class and then select Compare With -> or Replace With -> Local History... or Restore fromLocal History.